# Stopping Torque from looping in CartoDB editor

Tags: carto, torque

I'm working on a torque map and would like it to just animate once and then stop. I've found loop=false, but am unsure if I can apply this in any way when I'm using the CartoDB editor.

Does anyone know if that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly possible from the Editor at the moment, you need to use CartoDB.js for that. Check this example by @javisantana [here](http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/9189602). It's detecting the last torque step and pausing the reproduction there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Easy example | CartoDB.js</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
 </style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- include cartodb.js library -->
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>

<script>
  function main() {
    cartodb.createVis('map', 'http://javi.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/d4a5c7e4-4ad6-11e3-ab17-3085a9a9563c/viz.json', {
        shareable: true,
        title: true,
        description: true,
        search: true,
        tiles_loader: true
    })
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      // there are 3 layers
      // - base color (gray)
      // - circuit
      // - car (blue)

      // torque layer is the third one (0 based index)
      var torqueLayer = layers[2]
      // listen for every animation step
      // and pause when we reach the map steps
      torqueLayer.on('change:time', function(changes) {
        if (changes.step === torqueLayer.provider.getSteps() - 1) {
          torqueLayer.pause();
        }
      })
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  window.onload = main;
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```